# SQLDriverConnect error and no diagnostic output

Tags: odbc

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL database using SQLDriverConnect:

```
    int DatabaseHelper::ConnectDatabase()
{
    SQLSMALLINT i, MsgLen;
    SQLWCHAR SqlState[6];
    SQLRETURN rc2;
    SQLINTEGER NativeError[1];
    SQLWCHAR Msg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    retCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle);
    if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS)
        return retCode;
    retCode = SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS)
        return retCode;
    retCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnectionHandle);
    if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS)
        return retCode;
    retCode = SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnectionHandle, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)L"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server = 192.168.56.56\SQLEXPRESS;Database = PCTOOLS; Uid = sa; Pwd = delphi2006; ", SQL_NTS, retConString, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    i = 1;
    rc2 = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlConnectionHandle, i, SqlState, NativeError,
        Msg, sizeof(Msg), &MsgLen);
    return retCode;
}
```

When running, retCode gets the value -1, while rc2 will get the value -2. There is no value returned in SqlState, NativeError or Msg (they remain at the uninitialized values).
I am using Visual C++ 2015.

Comment: And you think that‘s a problem with C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Server =` attribute looks suspect on the `SQLDriverConnect` line.

Try using `Server = 192.168.56.56\\SQLEXPRESS` (note the double backslash) to escape the single backslash you're trying to pass through to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Phil for pointing in the correct direction.

SQLDriverConnect failed due to the single backslash in the server name and due to the spaces between the attributes of the connection string.

SQLGetDiagRec failed due to incorrect handle type - should have been SQL_HANDLE_DBC

Correct SQLDriverConnect call:

```
retCode = SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnectionHandle, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)L"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=192.168.56.56\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PCTOOLS;Uid=sa;Pwd=delphi2006;", SQL_NTS, retConString, 1024, &dwLength, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
```

Correct SQLGetDiagRec call:

```
rc2 = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlConnectionHandle, i, SqlState, NativeError,
        Msg, sizeof(Msg), &MsgLen);
```